# Where does PHP Composer store path to PHP binary?

Tags: php, composer-php

My Windows 7 PC for some reason will not load the PHP cURL module regardless of which WAMP server software package I install.  This isn't a huge issue most of the time as most libraries will use an alternative function.

My question is about this message I get in my terminal window when I run composer commands on packages that try to use curl....

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'G:\php\ext\libcurl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Notice above in the error I get from composer it is referencing my G drive `G:\php\ext\libcurl.dll`.  My current dev server and active PHP is located in my `E` drive here `E:\Dev_Server\php`

I checked my Windows `PATH` property to make sure a reference to the old G drive PHP wasn't stuck in there somewhere and it is not.  My new E drive is in my path.  So I am wondering where Composer is storing the G drive PHP reference so I can update that, any ideas?

Comment: Check your `PATH` environment variable. Remember you have to re-open your terminal for PATH changes to take effect. Also: Just `php -i` in your terminal provides useful information on paths.

Comment: I belive, that you "extension_dir" entry for php.ini file focused on "G:\php\ext\" directory, instead of "E:\Dev_Server\php\ext". Check also your php-cli.ini file for the same, if exists. It's not composer fault, but interpreter configuration;

Answer (score 0):

PHP CLI (which Composer uses) and PHP WAMP (which, well, WAMP uses) use different configuration files. Composer by itself does not store anything about your PHP installation.

What to do: Run `php --ini` and `php -i | more` from command line (`cmd.exe`). Check which configuration files PHP CLI uses and check what is configured there. You probably will find references to your `G:` drive there.